# Flash communication with asterisk server?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, asterisk, rtmfp

I want to deploy a web caller. And for this, I will use Flash. But I have no idea how to communicate with my server to relay the call through asterisk.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opensource way do that - use red5 flash server or http://code.google.com/p/siprtmp/ project.

But i hihgly recomend you use already developed components, for example flashphoner.com  if you are not expert in this field.

Comment: do you know if flashphoner quality is good or not? I mean, from flash player > flashphoner server (rtmp to sip converter) > asterisk > sip phone is a long path!  What other options there are? XMPP ?

Comment: Main problem here is not path, but flash itself and settings on users side. So if you not understand what issues can be - use already developed packages.